# PHP search function to look in pgsql table

Tags: php, postgresql, search

I want to make a search function in my website. I want to search for a string in all fields of my table (about 13 columns). If one row contains a field that matches the string (like operator) I want it to be added to result.

Example

```
|field 1 | field 2 | field 3|
 some      string     test    
 test      some      string
 one       simple    string
```

Now basically if I search for the string "test" I want to have the first two rows.

Is there a wildcard option for WHERE that I could do something :

SELECT * from my.table WHERE * like '%string%';

Comment: No, you need to write the `WHERE` clause. It's much less typing than you did to write this question. Just throw the column names into an array and loop over it to produce the list of `OR`ed comparisons.

Comment: Whatever technique you use, it's going to produce a dead slow query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such syntax in PostgreSQL (or any other DBMS).

As Spudley pointed out using a query like `like '%string%'` will be quite slow.

If this is something that is needed very often you should definitely look into PostgreSQL's full text search capabilities.